# Adding dates to list items in nested lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, date, nested-lists

I have as input a list of lists, (sample below) - and what I am trying to get out is the following

1) If the current month is in year first half, then for i in input dates add the current_year to the end of i. And also for i in year_second_half add yr + 1 to i in input dates which fall in year_second_half

Example - '5th August 19:45' becomes '5th August 19:45 2018' and  '2nd January 15:00' becomes '2nd January 15:00 2019'

2) If the current month is in year_second_half, then for i in input_dates add the current year to the end of i where the month is in year second half. And also for all months in i
which fall in year first half, add yr - 1 to those

Example (presume month is May) - '6th April 15:00' becomes '6th April 15:00 2018' and '5th August 19:45 2017'

```
currentYear = datetime.now().year
this_yr = currentYear

currentMonth = datetime.now().month
this_month = currentMonth

year_first_half = ['August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
year_second_half = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May']

input_dates =   [['5th August 19:45','8th December 12:30','16th December 16:00',
                '3rd January 20:00','12th January 15:00','19th January 15:00','30th January 20:00',
                '2nd February 15:00'],['9th December 15:00','23rd December 15:00',
                '27th December 20:00','2nd January 15:00','9th January 15:00',
                '6th April 15:00','27th April 15:00','4th May 15:00','12th May 15:00']]

newlist = []

for x in input_dates:
    for i in x:
        for month in year_first_half:
            if month in i and this_month in year_first_half:
                i = (i + ' {}').format(this_yr)
            elif month in i and this_month in year_second_half:
                i = (i + ' {}').format(this_yr - 1)    

        for month in year_second_half:
            if month in i and this_month not in year_second_half:
                i = (i + ' {}').format(this_yr + 1)

            elif month in i and this_month in year_second_half:
                i = (i + ' {}').format(this_yr) 



        newlist.append(i)
print(newlist)
```

Current output -

```
['5th August 19:45 2018', '8th December 12:30 2018', '16th December 16:00 2018', '3rd January 20:00 2019', '12th January 15:00 2019', '19th January 15:00 2019', '30th January 20:00 2019', '2nd February 15:00 2019', '9th December 15:00 2018', '23rd December 15:00 2018', '27th December 20:00 2018', '2nd January 15:00 2019', '9th January 15:00 2019', '6th April 15:00 2019', '27th April 15:00 2019', '4th May 15:00 2019', '12th May 15:00 2019']
```

This seems to be working but I would like to output the list of lists basically in the exact same format and order that I received it except for adding the year, as shown above.

When I run my code I just receive one list. Is there a better way to do this? The aim of this task is just to update the list with the correct years.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what happens here is that the 1st `for` loop of `input_dates` runs **two** times as you have 2 lists inside a list(input_dates). Hence you need to create another list which will append the list that was created in execution of each for loop.

Also I have modified the logic of the code.

**Here is the modified code:**

```
from datetime import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

currentYear = datetime.now().year
currentMonth = datetime.now().strftime("%B")

year_first_half = ['August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
year_second_half = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May']

input_dates =   [['5th August 19:45','8th December 12:30','16th December 16:00',
                '3rd January 20:00','12th January 15:00','19th January 15:00','30th January 20:00',
                '2nd February 15:00'],['9th December 15:00','23rd December 15:00',
                '27th December 20:00','2nd January 15:00','9th January 15:00',
                '6th April 15:00','27th April 15:00','4th May 15:00','12th May 15:00']]

outer_list = []
for x in input_dates:
    inner_list = []
    for i in x:
        each_entry = parse(i)
        if currentMonth in year_first_half:
            if each_entry.strftime("%B") in year_first_half:
                i = (i + ' {}').format(currentYear)
            else:
                i = (i + ' {}').format(currentYear + 1)
        elif currentMonth in year_second_half:
            if each_entry.strftime("%B") in year_second_half:
                i = (i + ' {}').format(currentYear)
            else:
                i = (i + ' {}').format(currentYear - 1)
        inner_list.append(i)
    outer_list.append(inner_list)
print(outer_list)
```

Comment: Thanks. Ran this and this returns two lists the same. I wanted the returned lists to look like input _dates except with the correct_yr placed at the end of each list item in each list.

Comment: Naveen see my previous comment

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions on how do what I need?

Comment: @anfield I have modified your logic.

Comment: naveen thanks. This is definitely good. The only thing is it prints the list  of lists twice, with the same elements

Comment: Can you share the output that you get. It runs fine in my case.

Comment: Ive edited my original post with the ouput, here it is below also  [['5th August 19:45 2018', '8th December 12:30 2018', '16th December 16:00 2018', '3rd January 20:00 2019', '12th January 15:00 2019', '19th January 15:00 2019', '30th January 20:00 2019', '2nd February 15:00 2019'], ['9th December 15:00 2018', '23rd December 15:00 2018', '27th December 20:00 2018', '2nd January 15:00 2019', '9th January 15:00 2019', '6th April 15:00 2019', '27th April 15:00 2019', '4th May 15:00 2019', '12th May 15:00 2019']]

Comment: @anfield: but you asked for same format as `input_dates`. Please do edit your questions and post your desired output. I can modify it based on your desired output.

Comment: thanks. this does work correctly. For some reason it was printing the output twice but not now